# Display Chinese and English Characters Conky

Tags: conky, language

So I'm trying to add kind of a word of the day thing to conky, but with Chinese words. There's a few ways I've tried this and with no success.

I have my words saved in a csv file formatted like

`电脑,dia4nna3o,computer`

In conky I've tried running

`${exec mycommand}`

Where mycommand has been several things:

1) Writing a python script that will print out a random line. Results in nothing (works in bash)

2) A bash script that echos the a random line. Results in nothing (works in bash)

3) Trying to convert the output from one of the above to an image and then displaying that image. Using

`python randword.py | convert label:@- tmp.png`

to convert the text to an image. While this displays an image, there is nothing where the Chinese character should be (but the English characters are there). Looks like this:

[image: Output image]

I'm really at a loss of what to do. Any idea?

---

System Info: 
Distro: Manjaro x86_64
DE: XFCE
Conky Version:

```
[ steven ] [~] > conky --version                                        
conky 1.10.6_pre compiled Thu Dec 29 16:29:51 UTC 2016 for Linux 4.1.37-1-MANJARO x86_64

Compiled in features:

System config file: /etc/conky/conky.conf
Package library path: /usr/lib/conky


 General:
  * math
  * hddtemp
  * portmon
  * IPv6
  * Curl
  * RSS
  * Weather (METAR)
  * Weather (XOAP)
  * wireless
  * support for IBM/Lenovo notebooks
  * nvidia
  * builtin default configuration
  * old configuration syntax
  * Imlib2
  * apcupsd
  * iostats
  * ncurses
  * Internationalization support

 Lua bindings:
  * Cairo
  * Imlib2
  * RSVG
 X11:
  * Xdamage extension
  * Xinerama extension (virtual display)
  * XDBE (double buffer extension)
  * Xft
  * ARGB visual
  * Own window

 Music detection:
  * MPD
  * MOC

 Default values:
  * Netdevice: eth0
  * Local configfile: $HOME/.conkyrc
  * Localedir: /usr/share/locale
  * Maximum netdevices: 64
  * Maximum text size: 16384
  * Size text buffer: 256
```

Comment: Does the font you are using in conky contain glyphs for the desired characters?

Comment: I can only display English characters in conky. Even things like the `├─` from `lsblk` do not show. I'm not sure how to get other symbols or fonts loaded. Let alone a mixed one.

Answer (score 3):

You will need to have a suitable font, and also set the locale for conky. I tried the following on a Linux Fedora using conky 1.10.4.  Install a font:

```
sudo dnf install google-noto-cjk-fonts
```

Create a file with some utf8 character:

```
    printf '\xe5\xba\x83\n' >chars
```

Create a `.conkyrc` that sets a global cjk font, and also tries setting a variant within the text part, and uses `cat` to read the above file:

```
conky.config = {
    minimum_height = 400,
    minimum_width = 600,
    font = 'Noto Sans CJK TC Regular:size=40',
    use_xft = true,
 };
conky.text = [[
 start  ${exec cat chars}  end
 ${font Noto Sans CJK TC Bold:size=20} start ${exec cat chars} end ${font}
]]
```

Run conky in a utf8 locale

```
    LC_ALL=en_US.utf8 conky -c .conkyrc -o
```

to get the result:

[image: conky]

Comment: Seems like something else is going on. With ONLY what you put in the conkyrc file I still get the square that represents unknown symbol. Again, catting chars shows the correct thing in the terminal. I'll update my post for system info

Comment: Your conky info is the same as mine. Presumably, `fc-match 'Noto Sans CJK TC'` shows `NotoSansCJK-Regular.ttc` as a match.

Comment: That would be correct. I get the same output.

Comment: Using 'Regular' in the font name did not work for me. But it worked without it.